# Spreadsheet Help: Adding Multiple Rows With "If" Function

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, openoffice.org

I'm trying to find the sum of all prices of the items on the list, minus the ones that have not sold in one cell on a spread sheet.

This Function works fine, but it takes a while to type, if you have like 20 items listed.

> =IF(D3="y";E3;0)+IF(D4="y";E4;0)+IF(D5="y";E5;0)+IF(D6="y";E6;0)+IF(D7="y";E7;0)+IF(D8="y";E8;0)

I've Tried:

> =IF(D3:D10="y";SUM(E3:E10);0)

But it doesn't work. I'm using OpenOffice.
I would post a picture, but no rep points.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(D3:D10;"y";E3:E10)
```

*Syntax*:

SUMIF(test_range; condition; sum_range)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SUMPRODUCT. 
[OO guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_SUMPRODUCT_function)

Specifically

```
SUMPRODUCT(D3:D10="y"; E3:E10)
```